# Solving `/dev/loop17` already mounted or mount point busy

Tags: mount, iso

I'm trying to follow [these](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot) instruction on how to install Ubuntu 22.04 without using a thumb-drive. I'm currently on 20.04.

I've downloaded the iso already but when I run the command

`sudo mount -o loop ubuntu-22.04-beta-desktop-amd64.iso /media/iso/`

I get the message

```
mount: /media/iso: /dev/loop17 already mounted or mount point busy.
```

Which when I loop up using

```
ps aux | grep loop17
```

I get back

```
root       36661  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   00:08   0:00 [loop17]
```

But running

```
sudo kill -9 36661
```

So I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Hello. Ubuntu 22.04 does not exist yet. Question about it are off topic at this time. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wrongly entered the ISO name, you get the message "**failed to setup loop device for** "

If you mount the ISO image to unknown directory, it's mean that directory doesn't exist in the path, you got the message like this "**mount point does not exist**"

Note:
"**lsblk**" command used to find what devices are already mounted.